# How to add background-image using ngStyle (angular2)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

How to use ngStyle to add background-image?
My code doesn't work:

```
this.photo = 'http://dl27.fotosklad.org.ua/20121020/6d0d7b1596285466e8bb06114a88c903.jpg';

<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': url(' + photo + ')}"></div>
```

Comment: why do you use the brackets on ngStyle attribute?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax about an related issue in RC.1

Answer (score 301, accepted):

I think you could try this:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + photo + ')'}"></div>
```

From reading your `ngStyle` expression, I guess that you missed some "'"...

Comment: Tested. Working with RC.1. It should't be needed for RC.2 and newer releases according to what they say [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax)

Comment: I prefer `this.photo = \`url(${photo})\`;`  `[style.background-image]='photo'`.

Comment: Bear in mind that spaces in picture URL (picture name) may cause a silent `[ngStyle]` and `[style.background-image]` rendering failure.

Comment: This is good. I once used it and it works well. Good one 

Answer (score 103):

Also you can try this:

`[style.background-image]="'url(' + photo + ')'"`

Comment: @redfox05 I suppose ngStyle is a syntactic sugar. The main difference is that ngStyle allows you to apply several css rules, but [style.<css_prop>] allows only one. The next are equivalent:
    `<div [ngStyle]="{ color: 'red', 'font-size': '22px' }">First</div>`

and

`<div [style.color]="'red'"
    [style.font-size.px]="22">Second</div>`

Comment: I've used this [style.css] approach, though I can't get [style.background-repeat] to work, you know why?

Comment: How to do conditional styling using this approach? Let's say if I want to check if photo is not null and then only apply this style?

Answer (score 34):

```ts
import {BrowserModule, DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser'

  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
    this.name = 'Angular!'
    this.backgroundImg = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('url(http://www.freephotos.se/images/photos_medium/white-flower-4.jpg)');
  }
```

```ts
<div [style.background-image]="backgroundImg"></div>
```

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html
- [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax)
- [**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/LvvrasddybDc8nl6LlyR)

Answer (score 9):

Looks like your style has been sanitized, to bypass it try using bypassSecurityTrustStyle method from DomSanitizer.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeStyle } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss']
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  public backgroundImg: SafeStyle;
  @Input() myObject: any;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  ngOnInit() {
     this.backgroundImg = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('url(' + this.myObject.ImageUrl + ')');
  }

}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="backgroundImg.length > 0" [style.background-image]="backgroundImg"></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use Instead

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image':' url(' + instagram?.image + ')'}"
```

Answer (score 6):

My background image wasn't working because the URL had a space in it and thus I needed to URL encode it.

You can check if this is the issue you're having by trying a different image URL that doesn't have characters that need escaping.

You could do this to the data in the component just using Javascripts built in [encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) method.

Personally I wanted to create a pipe for it so that it could be used in the template.

To do this you can create a very simple pipe.
For example:

src/app/pipes/encode-uri.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'encodeUri'
})
export class EncodeUriPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return encodeURI(value);
  }
}
```

src/app/app.module.ts

```
import { EncodeUriPipe } from './pipes/encode-uri.pipe';
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
  ],
 declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EncodeUriPipe
 ],
 bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

src/app/app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line
  selector: 'body',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
export class AppComponent {
  myUrlVariable: string;
  constructor() {
    this.myUrlVariable = 'http://myimagewith space init.com';
  }
}
```

src/app/app.component.html

```
<div [style.background-image]="'url(' + (myUrlVariable | encodeUri) + ')'" ></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use 2 methods:

### Method 1

```html
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(&quot;' + photo + '&quot;)'}"></div>
```

### Method 2

```html
<div [style.background-image]="'url(&quot;' + photo + '&quot;)'"></div>
```

Note: it is important to surround the URL with **"** char.

Answer (score 4):

Mostly the image is not displayed because you URL contains spaces. 
In your case you almost did everything correct. Except one thing - you have not added single quotes like you do if you specify background-image in css
I.e.

```
.bg-img {                \/          \/
    background-image: url('http://...');
}
```

To do so escape quot character in HTML via \'

```
                                          \/                                  \/
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(\''+ item.color.catalogImageLink + '\')'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution, using if..else statement. It is always a good practice if you want  to avoid unnecessary frustrations, to check that your variable exists and is set. Otherwise, provide a backup image in case; You can also specify multiple style properties, like `background-position: center`, etc.

```js
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': this.photo ? 'url(' + this.photo + ')' : 'https://placehold.it/70x70', 'background-position': 'center' }"></div>
```