# Attribute property binding for background-image url in Angular 2

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I have been struggling to figure out the best way to dynamically change the `background-image` attribute in a number of **Angular 2** components.

In the following example, I am attempting to set the `background-image` of a div to an `@Input` value  using `[ngStyle]` directive:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../models';

// exporting type aliases to enforce better type safety (https://github.com/ngrx/example-app)
export type UserInput = User;

@Component({
  selector: 'profile-sidenav',
  styles: [ `
    .profile-image {
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 50%;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
  `],
  template: `  
    <div class="profile-image" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': url({{image}})">
    <h3>{{ username }}</h3>
  `
})

export class ProfileSidenav {
  @Input() user: UserInput;
  blankImage: string = '../assets/.../camera.png';

  // utilizing "getters" to keep templates clean in 'dumb' components (https://github.com/ngrx/example-app) 
  get username() {
    return this.user.username;
  }
  get image() {
    if (!this.user.image) { return this.cameraImage;
    } else { return this.user.image; }
  }
```

I don't think the issue is with the observable, since `username` displays and doing something like `<img *ngIf="image" src="{{ image }}">` renders the image.  I have to access the `background-image` attribute because apparently that is the best way to make a circular image, but in general would like to know how to do this.

EDIT:

My original `[ngStyle]` declaration had unnecessary curly brackets (ngStyle is a directive that can take a variable), and was missing string tags around `url()` and `image`.  The correct way is (as answered below) is:

```
<div class="profile-image" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + image + ')'}"></div>`.
```

As **stated** in the original edit, a solution can also be achieved with the [Renderer](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html) class in Angular 2. I have yet to do it but think there should be a way with `setElementStyles`or something like that. I will try to post an example but would love if someone else showed me (and others) how to for the time being.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I think that you should use something like that:

```
<div class="profile-image"
     [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + image + ')'}">
```

where `image` is a property of your component.

See this question:

- [How to add background-image using ngStyle (angular2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875426/how-to-add-background-image-using-ngstyle-angular2/34875479#34875479)

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I tried your suggestion (with an extra curly bracket at the end, and the image didn't render :/. Also tried this and had no luck: `<div class="profile-image" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + {{image}} + ')'}">`

Comment: Does it have to do with how I have `image` defined? Your example (plus the extra curly bracket) does not cause any errors, but the image still does not render :/.  I tried putting `blankImage` in there as well (defined locally instead of through an observable), but had the same result. @Thierry

Comment: You're welcome! Is the `background-image` style applied to your element? You can see this within the Elements tab of Dev tools...

Comment: No, the style is not getting applied @Thierry Templier

Comment: (But is applied when I defined it in the .profile-image css up top)

Comment: Nvm, got it to work. The `blankImage` I was referencing had some blank spaces in the path, so that was causing the issue.

Comment: tried editing your response to add the extra curly bracket but it wasn't 6 characters (minimum required). Please edit so I can accept! Thanks !

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37233523#37233523

Answer (score 43):

You don't need to use `NgStyle`. You can also do this:

```
[style.background-image]="'url(' + image + ')'"
```

See more at [How to add background-image using ngStyle (angular2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875426/how-to-add-background-image-using-ngstyle-angular2)

Comment: Awesome! Really simple way. Thanks.

Comment: @moreirapontocom glad it helps, even 3 years on from when I wrote that :D

Comment: great! looking for this.

Answer (score 3):

[redfox05's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41051146/5541434) works well since there is no space in the image URL, but by a bit change in code we can make it work again:

```html
<div style.background-image="url('{{image}}')"></div>"
```

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is simple, you declared a global variable as `blankImage` but in the template you called `image` instead of `blankImage`.

Your ts code variable `blankImage`

```
blankImage: string = '../assets/.../camera.png';
```

Your template code variable `image`

```
<div class="profile-image" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + image + ')'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue and came up with a solution that works for image paths which contain spaces.

Within your component's HTML, add the style as follows where _imageBGPath is a property of your component.

**Component HTML**

```
<div [style.background-image]="'url(' + _imageBGPath + ')'">
...
</div>
```

Within your component declaration, add an input property so that we can run encodeURI on the supplied value to account for spaces.

**Component Declaration**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'image-display',
  templateUrl: './imageDisplay.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ImageDisplay.component.css'],
  providers: []
})
export class ImageDisplayComponent {
  @Input() set imageBGPath(value: string | undefined) {
    if (value != undefined && value != null) {
      this._imageBGPath = encodeURI(value);
    }
  };

  public _imageBGPath: string = "";

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Now when you reference your component, you can supply the path to your image.  If supplying inline with the component then you need to enclose it with '' so that angular knows this is a string being supplied and not a variable.

```
<image-display [imageBGPath]="'assets/Image With Spaces.jpg'"></image-display>
```

Answer (score -3):

that's wrong

I think you should add:

```
<div class="profile-image" [ngStyle]="{ 'backgroundImage': url({{image}})">
```

Regards

Comment: the RHS part already contains an expression, and you are adding another expression {{image}} into that. This will trigger an error.