# How to put background image in angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-inputs

I tried putting background url for my image

```
 <div  [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mysite/l/{{event.photo}} + ')'}"></div>
```

I am getting this error

```
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected
```

Can anyone please hepl me.Thanks.

Comment: {{}} cannot be used in `ngXXX`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to build the styleString in the controller. The just use a simple variable in your code. Much cleaner this way.

Comment: Fribu is undeniably right - you should keep your data out of view.
If you don't want to change your manner this time, remove interpolation brackets like this:
`'url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mysite/l/' + event.photo + ')'`

Answer (score 1):

Yor can't use property binding & interpolation together.

So try using the below code only `property binding`

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mysite/l/' + event.photo + ')'}"></div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this instead:**

```
<div  [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mysite/l/'+event.photo+')'}"></div>
```

that works fine as of angular v4 and later

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [style.background-image]

```
<div [style.background-image]="'url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mysite/l/'+ event.photo +')'">
```

Answer (score -1):

I would like you verify above link to get better idea on background images

[Angular2 dynamic background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575368/angular2-dynamic-background-images)

[Attribute property binding for background-image url in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577343/attribute-property-binding-for-background-image-url-in-angular-2)

Thank you