# How to use ngStyle for background url in Angular 4

Tags: image, angular

I have below html:

```
  <li>
    <div class="w3l_banner_nav_right_banner1" style="background:url('./assets/images/2.jpg') no-repeat 0px 0px;">
        <h3>Make your <span>food</span> with Spicy.</h3>
            <div class="more">
                <a href="products.html" class="button--saqui button--round-l button--text-thick" data-text="Shop now">Shop now</a>
            </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

**Problem:**

I want to replace image url `/assets/images/2.jpg` with dynamic variable like `{{ article.uri }}`.

I tried with several way from below ref:

[Attribute property binding for background-image url in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577343/attribute-property-binding-for-background-image-url-in-angular-2)

[How to add background-image using ngStyle (angular2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875426/how-to-add-background-image-using-ngstyle-angular2)

**Tried so far:**

```
<li *ngFor="let article of arr;let i=index;">
   <div  *ngIf="i == 0" class="w3l_banner_nav_right_banner" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-url': 'url('+article.uri+')'} no-repeat 0px 0px;">
     <h3>Make your <span>food</span> with Spicy.</h3>
            <div class="more">
                <a href="products.html" class="button--saqui button--round-l button--text-thick" data-text="Shop now">Shop now1</a>
            </div>
    </div>

</li>
```

I am using Angular 4.1.3.

Comment: "background-url" doesn't exist, at least not anymore.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`background-url` is incorrect CSS, use `background` or `background-image` instead.

Here is an example of correct syntax:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background': '#fff url(' + article.uri + ') no-repeat 0 0'}"></div>
```

Your full example would look like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let article of arr; let i=index;" >
   <div *ngIf="i == 0" 
         class="w3l_banner_nav_right_banner" 
         [ngStyle]="{'background': '#fff url(' + article.uri + ') no-repeat 0 0'}" >
     <h3> Make your <span>food</span> with Spicy. </h3>
            <div class="more">
                <a href="products.html" class="button--saqui button--round-l button--text-thick" data-text="Shop now">Shop now1</a>
            </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 12):

If you're getting your background image from a remote source or a user input you will need to have [angular sanitize the url](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer). In your component you will want to add the following bits of code...

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class YourComponent {
  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  public sanitizeImage(image: string) {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${image})`);
  }
}
```

Try setting your HTML to this...

```
<li *ngFor="let article of arr;let i=index;">
   <div  *ngIf="i == 0" class="w3l_banner_nav_right_banner" [style.background-image]="sanitizeImage(article.uri)">
     <h3>Make your <span>food</span> with Spicy.</h3>
            <div class="more">
                <a href="products.html" class="button--saqui button--round-l button--text-thick" data-text="Shop now">Shop now1</a>
            </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

And apply the `no-repeat 0px 0px;` in some class you attach to the div.

Comment: but why `style.background-image` as it was `background-url` ? also `no-repeat 0px 0px;` was for `url` properties,if it is `image` then for which properties it should be applied?

Comment: `background-url` isn't a CSS property from what I've known (if you scroll down a little you can see all the [background types here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp))

Comment: Missed the second half, you can just have a class that has `background: no-repeat 0px 0px;`

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is `[style.background-image]="'url(' + article.uri + ')'"`

but if you are using **ngFor** for carousel, make sure you have added class **'active'** properly.

This code will **NOT** working:

```html
    <div class="carousel-item active"
        *ngFor="let article of arr;"
        [style.background-image]="'url(' + article.uri + ')'"></div>
```

> You should use **'active'** class **for first item** only!

```html
    <div class="carousel-item" 
        *ngFor="let article of arr; let i = index;"
        [ngClass]="{'active': i === 0}"
        [style.background-image]="'url(' + article.uri + ')'"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it by adding url path in a single variable.
for example

```
bgImageVariable="www.domain.com/path/img.jpg";
```

> ```
> [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + bgImageVariable + ')'}"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Working for Angular 8+ (Power of template literals):
In component, define ngStyle object var (here called as styles, initialised in constructor):

```
const bgImageUrl = 'assets/images/dot-grid.png'
const styles = {
  backgroundImage: `url(${bgImageUrl})`
};
```

In template, assign this as ngStyle

```
<div [ngStyle]="styles"><!-- your content --></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following syntax worked:

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let page of pages">
    <div class="cardImage" style.background-image="url('{{ page.imageUrl }}')"></div>
</ion-slide>
```

Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.3

Answer (score -2):

This works fine for me:

**js file:**

```
path = 'url(../assets/about.png)';
```

**array:**

```
string[] = [this.path];
```

**and HTML file:**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of array" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': item}">
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -3):

To solve this, the correct syntax is

```
<div class="modalContainer" 
  ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + selectedMeal.url + ')'}">
```

Mark answer if it helps.

Comment: it's not happening

Comment: `ng-style` attribute? Are you providing an AngularJS/Angular 1 answer?

Comment: It's for angular 1 not for angular 4.
Regards