# Setting div background image from html attribute binding

Tags: css, django, angular, frontend, backend

I am trying to set a `background-image` for a div in a dynamic way from the backend.
I am using `django (djangorestframework)` as the backend.
I am sending a http request and this is the data I received:

```
{
        "user": "1ad54d3c-a012-431a-9e7a-8630fd9fb566",
        "image": "api/media/users/1ad54d3c-a012-431a-9e7a-8630fd9fb566/tutorials/yyyy/_image/tutorialImage.png",
        "title": "yyyy",
        "description": "hgdhgdh",
        "level": "professional",
        "parts": 0,
        "offical": false
 }
```

This is the html:

```
<div class="tutorial-card">
    <div class='tutorial-img' [style.background-image]="getTutorialImgURL(tutorial.image)">
</div>
```

The `getTutorialImageURL` function:

```
public getTutorialImgURL(path: string){
    return `url("http://${config.backendDomain}/${path}")`;
 } // config.backendDomain is "localhost:8000"
```

It doesn't appear to send a get request to the backend (the url path is right)

## things I have tried:

- changing the prefix from `http` to 'https'

  - it works but the backend doesnt yet support `https` so it returns `code 400`
- using `[ngStyle]="{'background-image': getTutorialImgURL(tutorial.image)}"`

  - still correct path but doesnt send the request
- make `getTutorialImgURL` return the full style (`return`image-backgr: url("http://${config.backendDomain}/${path}")`)

  - same as all corrent path not sending http requst
- using `DomSanitizer` `(return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url("http://${config.backendDomain}/${path}")`);)`

  - still, as before: correct path not sending http request to the backend

(I don't want to use `<img [src]='...'>`)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with binding to the style subproperty so instead you can use `ngStyle` to define the full inline styles. Using an example component:

```
@Component(
  {
    selector:'tutorial-image',
    template:`<div [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + imgUrl + ')'}"></div>`
  })
export class TutorialImage {
  @Input() path:string
  imgUrl: string

  ngOnInit(){
     this.imgUrl= `http://${config.backendDomain}/${path}`
  }
}
```

Note, if this is hosted on https it will not be able to retrieve images from a non-https endpoint (Mixed content error)

Solution adapted from: [Attribute property binding for background-image url in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577343/attribute-property-binding-for-background-image-url-in-angular-2/41051146)

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-poxtf2

Comment: still the same as all correct path but not sending the request to the backend server, it is sending only when the prefix is https

Comment: and is there any messages in the console? mixed content warning perhaps?

Comment: Nope and I have already tried using `DomSanitizer` just to be safe and still none

Comment: Yeah, from my own testing there seems to be a couple of issues with setting the background image from a template binding. But found an answer in another thread and have working so will update above

Comment: even in the demo you send in stackblitz if you change the URL prefix from `https` to `http` you wont get the image

Comment: Yes, please read the comment. If you serve a site on https you cannot link to assets hosted on http, it is a security feature present in web browsers.

Comment: so how `<img [src]='...'>` does it?

Comment: It doesn't. If you are serving from localhost or a http site you won't have the restriction. If you deploy to a https site you will have the restriction. I've updated the stackblitz with img tags and both http/https as further proof. I hope that answers your question.