# Better way of manipulating the DOM in Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

What's the better way of manipulating the `DOM` to change the background of a specific div, rather than using `document.getElementById('id').style.backgroundImage`.

I'm trying to change backgrounds as I change my Url, but the only way I could think and easy is using `document.getElementById()`

```
changeBg() {
 var urlPath = window.location.pathname.split('/');
  switch (urlPath[4]) {
    case "Refreshments%20North":
     document.getElementById('homeBg').style.backgroundImage = "url('./assets/imgs/spur-2.jpg')";
     break;
   ... more cases
    default:
     document.getElementById('homeBg').style.backgroundImage = "url('./assets/imgs/background.jpg')";
  }
}
```

I also tried `Renderer` dependency but how do I target `homeBg` using this?

```
this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'background-image', "url(./assets/imgs/spur-2.jpg)");
```

Template -- is basically just a div

```
<nav></nav>
<div id="homeBg"></div>
```

**Edit --**
Moved my `changeBg()` to my sharedService

```
public changeBg() {
var urlPath = window.location.pathname.split('/');
switch (urlPath[4]) {
  case "Refreshments%20North":
    this.homeBg = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("url('./assets/imgs/spur-2.jpg')");
    break;
  default:
    this.homeBg = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("url('./assets/imgs/background.jpg')");
  }
}
```

Calling `changeBg()` service in my profile component

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.sharedService.changeBg(); // is this correct?
}
```

Profile template -- like this gives me an error `Cannot read property 'homeBg' of undefined`

```
<div class="home" id="homeBg" [style.background-image]="changeBg?.homeBg"></div>
```

Change background with `route.param.subscribe()`

```
this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.sharedService.changeBg();
}
```

Comment: please, add your component template.

Comment: why don't you use JQuery?

Answer (score 3):

Using binding and directives is the preferred way in Angular2 instead of imperative DOM manipulation:

```ts
<div [style.background-image]="myService.homeBg"
```

You need to sanitize the URL for Angular to accept it.
See [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax) for more details.

```ts
changeBg() {
 var urlPath = window.location.pathname.split('/');
  switch (urlPath[4]) {
    case "Refreshments%20North":
     this.homeBg = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("url('./assets/imgs/spur-2.jpg')");
     break;
   ... more cases
    default:
     this.homeBg = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle( "url('./assets/imgs/background.jpg')");
  }
}
```

See also [How to add background-image using ngStyle (angular2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875426)

Comment: Can you check my edit line in my question if its correct, following your example code. I moved my `changeBg()` into my sharedService.

Comment: There seems to be a naming problem `mylocationbg` in `[style.background-image]="mylocationbg.homeBg"` points to a function but is used like a property.

Comment: should I remove `mylocationbg` and just call `this.sharedService.changeBg()` in the `ngOninit`? and do `[style.background..]="changeBg.homeBg"`? Actually nope that gave me an error instead.

Comment: If `changeBg` is the field that references your service, then yes. You might need to call `changeBg()` if the URL changes. You could to this by subscribing to the `Router` or to `window.hashchange` or what ever fits your use case.

Comment: Yeah I named it `changeBg` in my service, but when I change the template to `[style.background...]="changeBg.homeBg"` I get `Cannot read property 'homeBg' of undefined`.. `ngOninit { this.sharedService.changeBg()`

Comment: Try `[style.background...]="changeBg?.homeBg"` to not get an error while `changeBg` is not yet set.

Comment: I don't see the `[style.background..]` in the template when I inspect it. Also I'm triggering `changeBg` service on my `this.route.params.subscribe()..` See my edit.

Comment: You could try `bypassSecurityTrustUrl` or `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` instead of `bypassSecurityTrustStyle`. I'm not sure yet myself when exactly use which.

Comment: Still can't see it but using something like this `[style.background]="'url('+changeBg?.homeBg+')"` shows in the template but the `url()` value is `null`

Comment: Any idea why the value is `null`?

Comment: because string concatenation removes the sanitization marker.

Comment: also tried `[style.background]="changeBg?.homeBg"` but again I don't see any style in the template. Is there any work around?

Comment: Yeah it works if calling directly from its component but somehow not when its coming from a service :/

Comment: Try adding `<div>{{changeBg?.homeBg}}</div>` to see what value this actually returns. (alternatively `<div>{{changeBg?.homeBg | json}}</div>`)

Comment: `<div>{{changeBg?.homeBg | json}}</div>` returns `null`

Comment: Then `homeBg` doesn't get a value assigned.

Comment: Thought this would assign a value `this.homeBg = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("url('./assets/imgs/spur-2.jpg')")` or even just `this.homeBg = "test"`

Comment: I put a `console.log('Test')` in the `case "Refreshment..":` case and it printed the log, so its being executed, strange.

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple instances of the service (provided more than once). Can you reproduce in the Plunker?

Comment: Here's a plnkr sample, just forked yours and you should see `null` under the image https://plnkr.co/edit/lc9NAiifCvDfQKbdhUHM?p=preview, updated the plnkr removed the `switch` case.

Comment: It should be `[style.background-image]="sharedService?.swapBackground"`

Comment: I've already tried that and that wasn't showing anything even if you inspect the element.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I added the Plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/uUvovP5OoeNB0uLtAnEw?p=preview

Comment: Ah without the `changeBg()` function :/.. now that worked.

Comment: I updated my comment after about 2 minutes. You might have missed that. Glad to hear you could make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template references and `@ViewChild` decorator:

#### template :

```
<div #myDiv id="homeBg"></div>
```

#### component :

```
class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit{
    @ViewChild("myDiv")
    elRef:ElementRef

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'background-image', "url(./assets/imgs/spur-2.jpg)");
    }

}
```

Comment: what if the `homeBg` is in the parent?

Comment: You can't do this way. You must inject the parent in child, then send property to parent...

Comment: you are talking about the parent **component**, right ?

Comment: Yeah, my `switch` case condition is in my nav component, and `homeBg` is in profile. `<nav></nav>` template selector is in the profile component template.

Comment: Then no parent injection, you should create a service.