# Angular 2 style in microsoft edge

Tags: angular

`<div [style.background-image]="backgroundImg"></div>`

this doesn't work in microsoft edge. how i can fix that??

[How to add background-image using ngStyle (angular2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875426/how-to-add-background-image-using-ngstyle-angular2/43763344?noredirect=1#comment74567924_43763344)