# Variable inside style in HTML page not working in Angular 6

Tags: angular6

I need to add a background image in a span tag. The name of image is coming from Database. The code I had written is :

```
<span *ngIf="isSa === false" style ="background:url(assets/images/profile/{{emp_image}} ) no-repeat center"> </span>
```

The variable 'emp_image' is having a value '1.png' and it is getting if i am  printing it outside the style.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add background-image using ngStyle (angular2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875426/how-to-add-background-image-using-ngstyle-angular2)

Comment: check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzxvzf for working example