# background-image isn't working in Angular6 using ngStyle

Tags: angular6, ng-style

I want to set background-image dynamically using ngStyle. But it isn't loading anything. Here is my HTML

```
<div
  id="banner-cover"
  class="bg-parallax animated fadeIn"
  [ngStyle]="{
    'background-image': backgroundImage
  }"
>
...
</div>
```

And here is my backgroundImage() method defined in ts. Here I have used Domsanitizer which is recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43070098).

```
export class BannerComponent implements OnInit {
  public _backgroundImage = "'url('../../../../assets/images/bg-banner.jpg')'";
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  get backgroundImage() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle( this._backgroundImage );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the getBackgroundImage() method:

`[ngStyle]="{
    'background-image': getBackgroundImage()
  }"`

Comment: I've tried by calling both method and attribute. Neither of them worked. Here I've showed the attribute calling.