# Angular - how can i set an image from Api as background image

Tags: css, angular

I try to set an image i get from my api as background image from my header. But it will not work as expected...

This is my code:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header" [ngStyle]="{background: 'url('userProfile.headerImagePath')'}">
        ...
```

css

```
.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 500px;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

Comment: check this answer. this might helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875426/how-to-add-background-image-using-ngstyle-angular2

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code.

```
        <div class="header" [ngStyle]="{background: 'url('+userProfile.headerImagePath+')'}">
        ...
```